# Java Enum Type Coding Convention

Tags: java, enums, coding-style

I have an enum type...

```
public static enum Methods {
    NOTEQUAL,
    ORDERED,
    minMatch,
    minItem,
    minLength,
    sameLength,
}
```

The question is how should I use the coding convention. Should I use camelCase `NotEqual` (wich I use in a simple class) or should I do like this: `NOT_EQUAL`? Or simply use uppercase characters: `NOTEQUAL`, `SAMELENGTH`?

Is there some code convention for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069743/coding-conventions-naming-enums
have a look on that topic.

Comment: Ok, so the answer is "_" mark and high case i know i should use name like constants, but i didn't know how to articulation the name...

Comment: Anyway thank you Alex Stybaev and Alexender Pavlov, and not the exact duplicate, because the question was about how to !!!articulate!! the enums...

Comment: In this page from the official website of Java, constants should be capitalized by convention: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov It's not an exact duplicate, though very similar: This question focuses on enum *instances*, while the question you linked focused on the enums themselves.

Comment: @MathManiac: right, thanks for pointing out. I must have been looking at its top answer, which dealt both with enums and values together.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I would say that the enum itself, since it's a class, should follow the camel case convention as every class, while the entries of enum, since they are constants, should be upper case with underscore (eg. `NOT_EQUAL`).

The version uppercase without underscore is absolutely unreadable, never use it.

Comment: And the class name is usually singular (-> "Method" not "Methods")

Comment: Just for future reference, the [java people agree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html): `Because they are constants, the names of an enum type's fields are in uppercase letters.`

Answer (score 3):

See the following discussion:

[Coding Conventions - Naming Enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069743/coding-conventions-naming-enums)

My own point of view is that enum is like constants so they should be all uppercase.

Comment: An enum is quite certainly not like a constant, it is a type, like a class. The enumerated values could be considered to be like constants (if that's what you meant you should correct your wording). A variable of an enum type could be considered to be a constant, if declared final.