# Switch on Enum when strings contain dash

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I would like to use enum as a way of switching over strings, however java complains as my string contains "-". As seen in the code below where IC19-01 and IC19-02 contain "-".

```
public class CMain {
    public enum Model {
        IC19-01, IC19-02
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String st = "IC19-01"; 
        switch (Model.valueOf(st)) {
            case IC19-01: 
                System.out.println("Case IC19-01");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

What can i do for this?

Comment: why don't you replace `-` with `_`(underline)?

Comment: I will only if that is the last option. I wanna keep my code clean if possible.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible with Java, because each item has to be a valid identifier (and valid Java identifiers may not contain dashes).

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in Java as is. But you could do your own implementation as a work around, although it will yield more code. You could change your `enum` like the following:

```
 public enum Model {
    IC19_01("IC19-01"), 
    IC19_02("IC19-02")

    private final String name;

    private Model(String name){
     this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
       return name;
    }

   public static Model getByName(String aName){
         for(Model current: Model.values()){
           if(current.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(aName.trim())){
              return current;
           }
          }
          return null;
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to call `Model.getByName(st)` instead of `Model.valueOf`. Alternatively, in Java 7 you should be able to switch the actual `String`.

Comment: this solution will never work (current.equalsIgnoreCase doesn't exist)

Comment: equalsIgnoreCase is a method from String, it was intended to get name of current before the check. Edited to reflect that change

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

Enums are classes and should follow the conventions for classes. Instances of an enum are constants and should follow the conventions for constants.

> Blockquote

Details about this can be found on following link

[Coding Conventions - Naming Enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069743/coding-conventions-naming-enums)
Hope it helps