# How to match Enum Objects with their associated constant values?

Tags: java, enums

I created this enum:

```
public enum CoffeeSorts {
    Coffee("Kaffee"), Espresso("Espresso"), Mocca("Mocca"), Cappuccino(
            "Cappuccino"), LatteMacchiato("Latte Macchiato"), DoubleEspresso(
            "doppelter Espresso");

    private final String stringValue;

    private CoffeeSorts(final String s) {
        stringValue = s;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return stringValue;
    }
}
```

I tried the following way to use it

```
public ACoffee createCoffee(String type) {

        switch (type) {
        case CoffeeSorts.Cappuccino :
            try {
                return new ChocolateSprincles(new Cream(new Coffee()));
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            return null;
            break;
        case CoffeeSorts.LatteMacchiato :
            try {
                return new ...
            }
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

It only gives me an Error saying "cannot convert from CoffeeSorts to String".
Can you tell me what i did wrong?

Comment: can you be more specific? Maybe provide a stacktrace?

Comment: Compiler should be referenced as "it", not "He".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `type` variable is a `String`, but you're trying to specify *values* which are `CoffeeSort` values. You'll need to convert the `String` to a `CoffeeSort` first, or change the signature.

For example:

```
public ACoffee createCoffee(CoffeeSort type) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
public ACoffee createCoffee(String typeName) {
    CoffeeSort type = CoffeeSort.valueOf(typeName);
    ...
}
```

Also note that you can't `break;` after a `return` statement, as it's unreachable code. (I hope your exception handling isn't really like that, either...)

Finally, consider changing your code entirely to put a `createCoffee` method *inside the enum itself*. Then you won't need a switch statement at all. You can make it an abstract method which is overridden in each enum value.

```
public enum CoffeeSort {
    Coffee("Kaffee") {
        @Override public ACoffee createCoffee() {
           ...
        }
    },
    Espresso("Espresso") { ... },
    Mocca("Mocca") { ... },
    Cappuccino("Cappuccino") { ... },
    LatteMacchiato("Latte Macchiato") { ... },
    DoubleEspresso("doppelter Espresso") { ... };

    private final String stringValue;

    private CoffeeSorts(final String s) {
        stringValue = s;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return stringValue;
    }

    public abstract ACoffee createCoffee();
}
```

Comment: I like most of your post, but that pattern you're proposing with the factory methods inside the enum values is really not my cup of tea ;-)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: Coffee/tea differences, aside, it depends on the context. I *love* putting behaviour inside enums when it really belongs there - when it's not context-specific, for example. Is the `CoffeeSort` type the piece of code which should unambiguously know how to create a cup of coffee? If so, my solution is great IMO - polymorphism wins over switch/case where feasible. If, however, you've got different situations (e.g. "create a cup of coffee in XML form" vs "create a cup of coffee as JSON") then it's a different matter.

Comment: Agreed. It most certainly depends on the case.

Answer (score 4):

The `type` in your `switch(type)` should be an object of type `CoffeeSorts`. You're passing in a string.

Answer (score 2):

Your method signature should be:

`public ACoffee createCoffee(CoffeeSorts type)`

Your switch statement works on `type` and the case statements that you put there only make sense if `type` is of type `CoffeeSorts`.

Sidenote: enums are typically capitalized in Java (see [Coding Conventions - Naming Enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069743/coding-conventions-naming-enums)).