# How to convert String to Enum, changing to capital before that?

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum where

```
public enum Regular {
    NONE,
    HOURLY,
    DAILY,
    WEEKLY;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name().toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Where we could convert it to Lower case when we get it. But if I were to convert from String to Enum, I have to explicitly remember to set `toUpperCase()`

```
Regular.valueOf(regular.toUpperCase());
```

Is there a way to define this in my Enum class, where it will auto convert all string to UpperCase to compare it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to do it.

But, once you create another method `String getName()` to "override" the default implementation of `name()`. I thought that you have to do the same with `Regular valueOf()` ,i.e., create another method `Regular valueOfByName()`.

```
public enum Regular {
    NONE,
    HOURLY,
    DAILY,
    WEEKLY;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name().toLowerCase();
    }

    public static Regular valueOfByName(String name){
        return valueOf(name.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. just overload the function. How could I miss consider that!