# Boolean methods and enum in Java (NetBeans)

Tags: java

I have a question to make a program for Car Hiring Company. I am stuck in few questions and not sure about some of my answers, so I would appreciate it if anyone can help me.

At the beginning it required me to implement the status of a hire car using an enum type, with this information (current status (viz. on hire, available for hire, or being serviced). so I wrote:

```
private enum carStatus {On_Hire, Available_For_Hire, Being_Serviced};
```

Is this correct?

If so, we come to the question that I didn't know how to solve:

> Write three public boolean methods isAvailable, isOnHire and isBeingServiced to determine information about a hire car’s status.

Then it asks to write methods `hireOut`, `returnFromHire` and `returnFromService`.

I don't know what it wants from this question? anyone can give me a tip ?

Can anyone help me how to solve this one please.

Comment: By convention, constant names should be in all-uppercase: `ON_HIRE`, `AVAILABLE_FOR_HIRE` etc. The enum name itself should start with an uppercase, as it is a type name (like interfaces and classes). Also, the semicolon (`;`) at the end is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct - the variable namings could be improved though (see: [Coding Conventions - Naming Enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069743/coding-conventions-naming-enums))

Since you have three enum-values and need a public boolean method, you can write them as follows:

```
public boolean isAvailable() {
   return carStatus.Available_For_Hire.equals(myCarStatus);
}
```

This will return true, if the current car status field `myCarStatus` equals the enumeration value `Available_For_Hire`. To make this work, you'll need to add the field `myCarStatus` of type `carStatus` (which is your enum) to your class:

```
private carStatus myCarStatus;
```

Comment: I'd prefer `==` over `equals` for enums.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am not sure if I get the the second part of ur answer,, do I add the code ( private carStatus myCarStatus; ) below my enum code to make it work ?

Comment: @ASD123 You theoretically can add it where you want, but usually, fields are placed before methods in the class.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will add another question related to this I hope you can help me with it.

Comment: @flogy look at the edit and if you know what to do please help me

Comment: @ASD123 Please add more specific requirements to your question. Like that one can only guess what you are trying to do...

Comment: @flogy The question is just like that,,  write methods hireOut, returnFromHire and returnFromService.,, is there anyway I can contact you and show you the full question as there are some questions before they might be usefull but I don't know if they are related or no