# Way to save type of each item

Tags: java, enums

I am reading records from Excel to a POJO
I have created an enum to hold the order of each column

My question is Is it possible to save the column type as well?

so later I will pass this enum to some method it will know how to process the value based on its type...

for example:

```
public enum StudentInfo{
 name(0,String),
 age(1,Integer),
 height(2,Float),
 eyeColor(5,Color);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the class of the expected type as a field in the enum instances. You would construct them similarly to what you have now but like:

```
name(0, String.class),
```

Then you can have a

```
private Class<?> columnType;
```

as a field and use that.

As an aside, by convention (see [here](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.8.1-enum-classes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3069863/59087)), enum values are usually named in all upper case.

Comment: I ended up using org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType but thank you!